# Custom Iterator using boost iterator

Tags: boost, iterator, c++03, boost-iterators

I've a custom data structure like following:

```
class Node;

class GraphDM {
public:
    GraphDM();
    // these are to iterate on all items of _faninNodes 
    // like all elements in multimap
    FaninIter  faninBegin(); 
    FaninIter  faninEnd();

    // these are to iterate on all items of _fanoutNodes
    FanoutIter fanoutBegin();
    FanoutIter fanoutEnd();

    // these should work like equal_range of multimap
    std::pair<FaninIter, FaninIter > getFanins (const Node *node_);
    std::pair<FaninIter, FaninIter > getFanouts(const Node *node_);

private:
    typedef std::vector< Node* > NodeList;
    typedef boost::unordered_map< Node*, 
                                  NodeList > Map;

    Map     _faninNodes;
    Map     _fanoutNodes;
};
```

**I need to implement these APIs. How can I implement these using boost iterator library?**

Also, I may need to take a Predicate to allow filtering

Some pointer to get started will be very helpful. One clarification: I cannot use c++0x compiler flags as I need to use c++98 only. So, please suggest a solution that doesn't need c++11 or c++03 compiler flag.

Also, if I design an iterator like following (nested in the GraphDM class), I'm essentially exposing details my data-structure. Is there a way to make the iterator to iterate only on the Key's of the map (and not the value)? Then I can return a different type of iterator for the getFanins() and getFanout() which would be iterator from the value list.

```
   class Iter : public boost::iterator_adaptor< Iter,
                                                 Map::iterator,
                                                 boost::use_default >
    {
    public:
        Iter() : Iter::iterator_adaptor_() {}


    private:
        friend class GraphDM;

        Iter(Map::iterator it)
                : Iter::iterator_adaptor_(it) {}

        friend class boost::iterator_core_access;

    };
```

Comment: One clarification: I cannot use c++0x. So, please suggest a solution that doesn't need c++11 or c++03 compiler flag.

Comment: This is what I'm getting: You don't even know what compiler level you use and you want us to do your work for you. (Of course you **can** use c++03.). Also, edit your question. Tags are for tagging. Comments are not for editing.

Comment: "I may need to take a Predicate to allow filtering" - I ignored this as it is not part of a question, and it's unclear what it means (I can think of a few different things it could mean).

Comment: 1. What I meant on c++0x flag is that I cannot use either c++03 or c++11 flags. I'm using c++98.

Comment: For the filtering I meant something like following - let me term the nodes with in-degree more than 1 as multi-fanin node.  Now in fanoutBegin/fanoutEnd, I need to an ability which will filter so that I can get only the multi-fanin nodes or I get all but the multi-fanin nodes.

Comment: No living compiler that I know of compiles in c++98 mode if you don't pass any flags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any requirement in your text to be creating custom iterators. You can just typedef the iterators from the inner maps.

Here, I fixed some things:

- you can't usually apply `boost::hash<Node>` to a `Node const*`. If you don't specify the hash it will default `boost::hash<key_type>`, which is very likely what you want.
- There were some const correctness issues (the equal_range methods take const pointers). I've corrected everything towards the safe default of const-ness.

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/02a48017db5ddcad)</kbd>**

```
#include <utility>
#include <boost/unordered_map.hpp>
#include <vector>

struct Node {};

class GraphDM {
    typedef std::vector<Node const*> NodeList;
    typedef boost::unordered_map<Node const *, NodeList/*, boost::hash<Node const*>*/ > Id2NodeListMap;

  public:
    typedef Id2NodeListMap::const_iterator FaninIter;
    typedef Id2NodeListMap::const_iterator FanoutIter;

    GraphDM() {}

    FaninIter  faninBegin()  const;
    FaninIter  faninEnd()    const;

    FanoutIter fanoutBegin() const;
    FanoutIter fanoutEnd()   const;

    // these should work like equal_range of multimap
    std::pair<FaninIter, FaninIter> getFanins(Node const *node_) const;
    std::pair<FaninIter, FaninIter> getFanouts(Node const *node_) const;

  private:
    Id2NodeListMap _faninNodes;
    Id2NodeListMap _fanoutNodes;
};

GraphDM::FaninIter  GraphDM::faninBegin() const {
    return _faninNodes.begin();  
}

GraphDM::FaninIter  GraphDM::faninEnd()   const {
    return _faninNodes.end();
}

GraphDM::FanoutIter GraphDM::fanoutBegin() const {
    return _fanoutNodes.begin();
}

GraphDM::FanoutIter GraphDM::fanoutEnd()   const {
    return _fanoutNodes.end();
}

// these should work like equal_range of multimap
std::pair<GraphDM::FaninIter, GraphDM::FaninIter> GraphDM::getFanins(Node const *node_) const {
    return _faninNodes.equal_range(node_);
}
std::pair<GraphDM::FaninIter, GraphDM::FaninIter> GraphDM::getFanouts(Node const *node_) const {
    return _fanoutNodes.equal_range(node_);
}

int main() {
    GraphDM demo;
}
```

Comment: The value type of the unordered_map is a vector. And mine is not a multimap or unordered_multimap that I can use equal_range directly. The reason I'm using a vector is that I'd like to sort the elements in a specific way once the model is fully populated. But I think I get your point - I can as well typedef the iterator to vector and provide the api using that.

Comment: That was not really my point. You just didn't say anything about the behaviour expected,  and I did not assume complexity where it wasn't given.